# Obtaining initial state of target object in object:modified event in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, undo-redo

I have a drawing application that uses fabric.js and I have implemented an undo/redo function based on the fabric-history repository on github.  However, because this approach saves entire canvas states in a stack, the browser quickly becomes non-responsive as it deals with all this data.  I would like an undo/redo method that only saves the object that is changed in an interaction with an object on the canvas and not the whole canvas.  Using the object:modified event, I see I can get the target object of the event after it is modified, but I also need the object target state before the modification was made to restore it in an undo.  Any suggestions on how to obtain this state of an object would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `saveState` method for it. After calling this method object gets `_stateProperty` object that contains current values of left, top, and other properties. You can read more about `saveState` method in [doc](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#saveState)

I've made a simple example to demonstrate this approach [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-bird-gth4g?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Thanks for responding!  The link you provided wasn’t to an example but to the doc page.  Can you please update the link to your example.  It would really help me understand how to use saveState for my needs.

Comment: Thanks!  I've been playing with the example and trying to add  `filters` array to the `_stateProperties` object so that it will trigger an  `object:modified`, but the documentation for `saveState` is not clear how to do this and there were no examples. I need the `filters` saved because I am also coloring images and I want to be able to undo that coloring by reverting to the prior filter. I have tried using a number of different forms for the using `filters` in the argument of the `saveState` function without much success.  Do you know how it should be formatted?